# Can't resolve internal/private DNS entries over VPN connection - openvpn

Tags: dns, openvpn

I have my net interface (192.0.1.10) that is configured to a intranet private DNS server in (192.0.1.17). With this configuration the DNS server works well, i.e. testing with "telnet 192.0.1.17 53" it connect!

I configure the VPN client with the address 10.0.0.10 and added the "dhcp-option DNS 192.0.1.17" configuration to point to the intranet DNS, but when It's connected to the VPN, I can't no more telnet to the DNS server.

`"Connecting To 192.0.1.17...Could not open connection to the host, on port 53: Connect failed"`

I tried to add route 192.0.0.17 the route to the client to force the routing, but no way, I can't retrieve the server using the telnet.

Someone have one idea?

Thank you

Comment: Why is your intranet using addressess from [a "special-purpose" reserved range?](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml)

Comment: The VPN is used to over internet, and tjhe DNS is to resolve intranet names.